# Ruby Newton method gives incorrect result?

Tags: ruby, math

I have the following code that will try to solve a system of polynomials:

```
require "bigdecimal"
require "bigdecimal/newton"
include Newton

class Function
  attr_reader :zero, :one, :two, :ten, :eps
  def initialize()
    @zero = BigDecimal::new("0.0")
    @one  = BigDecimal::new("1.0")
    @two  = BigDecimal::new("2.0")
    @ten  = BigDecimal::new("10.0")
    @eps  = BigDecimal::new("1.0e-16")
  end

  def values(x) # <= defines functions solved
    f = []
    f1 = x[0] + x[1] - 7
    f2 = x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1] - 29
    f <<= f1
    f <<= f2
    f
  end
end
f = Function.new
x = [f.zero,f.zero]
nlsolve(f,x)
puts x.map(&:to_i)
```

This outputs [1,5]. Obviously is should be [2,5] as that is the correct solution to the system:

```
x + y = 7
x*x + y*y = 29
```

Perhaps the culprit is my `to_i` call on `BigDecimal`, but that shouldn't be as far as the math goes.

Any ideas?

### Bonus Question

The ruby stdlib says you can use this without BigDecimal, but passing floats to all the vars in `initialize` gives me this error:

`ruby/2.1.0/bigdecimal/ludcmp.rb:23:in 'div': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)`
.

Why is that?

Comment: Well, `1.999999999.to_i` doesn't return `2`, try `x.map(&:round)` :-)

Comment: Wow, I actually figured out this a second ago. Thank you sir. Any ideas about the bonus question I added?

Comment: I have no idea, it requires and uses `BigDecimal`

Comment: Please don't edit in a bonus question.  It breaks the Q&A format of SO.

Comment: @Stefan you wanna put the comment of your as an answer so that I mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In regards to the bonus question:**

I believe that the issue is that in bigdecimal/ludcmp.rb:

https://github.com/lian/ruby-bigdecimal-backport/blob/master/lib/bigdecimal/ludcmp.rb

on line 23, it is calling the div method on 'one'

```
scales <<= one.div(nrmrow,prec)
```

which you are passing in as a float, however the div method for a float takes one argument, whereas it takes two for bigdecimals. If you change all the vars in initialize to floats but keep

```
@one  = BigDecimal::new("1.0")
```

it will make it past line 23 of ludcmp.rb (although still erroring for the same reason later on in the code).

Comment: Thank you raph. Wouldn't this contradict the comment they have in documentation that the Newton module does not require BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `x.map(&:round)`

You loose precision when calling `.to_i` on a floating point number in ruby.

Example -

`1.999999999.to_i == 1 #=> true`

In this case you can call `.round` to get the expected output. i.e -

`1.999999999.round == 2 #=> true`

Comment: This is of course the answer to the OP's main question, as @Stephan points out in the accepted answer